# What does measuring a diode with a DMM's diode mode say about a circuit when the circuit is charged?

Tags: batteries, diodes, measurement, multimeter, voltage-measurement

I've never used diode mode before on my DMM, so when I went to measure a diode in my circuit, I had a battery attached to it. I want to understand these measurements.

I measured four devices each with the diode in question. Two are known good units and behave properly, two are bad devices and behave improperly. This exercise is an attempt to find out why the two bad devices are behaving improperly.

Firstly, Measuring the diode backwards and forwards **without a battery**, as I should have done initially, shows ~.214 on all four devices in the forward direction and 0 in the reverse, so they're consistent in that way.

Measuring the diode **with a battery attached**, which is the wrong way to do it, shows ~.214 in the forward direction, and then something different in the reverse (instead of zero.)

For the devices behaving properly, I see between .668 and .812.

For the devices behaving improperly, I see ~1.780.

The devices behaving improperly have a value approximately twice as high as the proper units. I'm trying to understand what this means for the circuit or for the diode in question.

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the diode context? To answer this, the complex interaction with other components must be known.

Answer (score 2):

Your measurements tell you nothing.

Measuring a diode with the diode function of your multimeter doesn't tell you anything useful about the diode - either with or without power to the circuit.

There are always things in parallel to the part you are trying to measure.  The meter can only measure the voltage that results from the current it applies.  All the other parts connected to the diode you are trying to measure draw current and mess up that measurement.  If the circuit is powered, they may also deliver current to the meter.

You can measure voltage in a circuit with your meter.  You can measure current through your circuit (but you'll have to cut a connection an put your meter in series with the circuit for it to work.)

Outside of that, the functions on the meter can only be relied on when the part you are testing is out of the circuit.

For two lead components all you have to do is disconnect one side.

---

Use your meter on powered circuits only to measure voltage or current.  Anything else may damage the meter.

If your circuit is powered from line voltage, such a mistake could cause real damage to your circuit, the meter, or to you.